# Micro SD card write protected fat32?

Tags: nautilus, mount, permissions, fstab, sd-card

I have tried this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213889/microsd-card-is-set-to-read-only-state-how-can-i-write-data-on-it) and it doesnt work.
`sudo fdisk -l` output is

```
Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0004a414

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      718847      358400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          718848   759897456   379589304+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       759898110  1465147391   352624641    5  Extended
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5      1448615936  1465147391     8265728   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       759898112  1448615935   344358912   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdb: 3960 MB, 3960471552 bytes
31 heads, 30 sectors/track, 8317 cylinders, total 7735296 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            8192     7735295     3863552    b  W95 FAT32
```

When apply 
`sudo mount --options remount,rw /dev/sdb1`

says:
`mount: cannot remount block device /dev/sdb1 read-write, is write-protected`

When apply this: `sudo chown -hR waqas /dev/sdb1`
it shows changing the permission of files and gives the log files but result is nothing when i goto the card and check the permission its the same. 

same case with the `sudo chmod -R 777 /dev/sdb1`

and the last one i apply `gksudo nautilus` when navigate to the card and try to change the permission it says:
 [image]
and window close after a second. So I am not sure what to do. 

Note:

Ubuntu 13.10
this card was in Android phone and somehow got messed up with the permissions. 
written on card: Micro SD card HC 4GB

Comment: Can you write to it in any other device?

Answer (score -1):

I just came across the same problem. The reason for the error message is that there is *physical* switch that prevents a write to the media. You SD adapters have one. But micro sd doesnt.

Solution: (Obvious :P) Flip the switch in the SD card adapter and plug it in.

Comment: micro card doesnt have switch on it where it is [IMAGE](http://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/c/4/1040078_1374562954_image1-3e87d.jpg) ?

Comment: Micro SD card doesnt have any physical switches. But an adapter for it is having one. http://www.cheapchips.com.au/resources/image/Micro%20SD%20to%20SD%20adapter.jpg In the left side you can see a small plastic movable thing. What did you mean @RanaMuhammadWaqas ?

Comment: I have that unlocked and it doesnt work either a way changed the adapter jacket even
 i thought you telling me there is a lock on micro sd card

Comment: In that case, I am out of option, sorry. Sometimes your adapter itself is damaged. Or perhaps when you plug it in, the switch automatically changes the state (mechanically) due to some congestion. I cant think of anything else.