# How To Write To SD card

Tags: 13.10, sd-card, helpfile, mod-rewrite

I heard of people saying they could if they did it as a root user. How do I do that. When I tried to write to sd card, I got a read only error.

Permissions says

```
Owner: me 
Access: Create and delete files
Group: disk
Access: None (cant change it ... get a permission error)
Other Access: None (same error)
```

Oh yea I have Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MicroSD card is set to Read-only state. How can I write data on it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213889/microsd-card-is-set-to-read-only-state-how-can-i-write-data-on-it)

Answer (score 0):

check related questions on the right of screen

one of the questions is:
MicroSD card is set to Read Only State. How can I write data on it.

here is the link:

[MicroSD card is set to Read-only state. How can I write data on it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213889/microsd-card-is-set-to-read-only-state-how-can-i-write-data-on-it?rq=1)

good luck, I am in the same boat, just came on line to check answers

Once there keep scrolling down there are several answers already posted