# System went into read only mode

Tags: server, filesystem, read-only

I am newbie in Ubuntu.

We have a cloud server in Rackspace with following configuration:

OS - Linux version 2.6.35.4-rscloud (root@builder.slicehost.com) (gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) ) #8 SMP Mon Sep 20 15:54:33 UTC 2010

Size - 2048 MB RAM, 80 GB Disk

About 5 hours ago system went to read-only mode. 1 hour ago we rescued it with `sudo fsck -Af` found here - [How to fix "sudo: unable to open ... Read-only file system"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197459/read-only-file-system)

Now I am checking `/var/log/dmesg*` but I am not able to understand the reason why did it went to read only mode.

It would be helpful if someone can point out how can we find the reason for system going in read only mode ?

Do let me know if any additional information is needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`/var/log/message*` are the files to check.

would suggest to log a ticket with rackspace asking them reason for instance to go into read-only mode.