# File system went read only after adding ssh key

Tags: 14.04, ssh, filesystem, read-only

I followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2) to set up ssh key on my digital ocean droplet, but since I made step 4 my file system went read-only. I changed `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` from `PermitRootLogin yes` to `PermitRootLogin without-password` and then `reload ssh`; and when I logged back in, I had no writing rights anymore.

I can log in using `ssh root@123.45.67.89` but it does not ask me for any password, and I can not modify any file.

Before doing this, I upgraded my ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04, it asked me during the upgrade which setting did I want for `PermitRootLogin` and when I looked at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` after the installation (and after adding my ssh key) it was set on `PermitRootLogin yes`.

--- update ---

After reading [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/312216/220228) answer I ran `dmesg | grep "EXT4-fs error"` to see if I have any issues related to the filesystem / journaling system itself.

It returned many times:

`[68241.757233] EXT4-fs error (device vda): htree_dirblock_to_tree:892: inode #533953: block 2108070: comm updatedb.mlocat: bad entry in directory: rec_len is smaller than minimal - offset=0(0), inode=0, rec_len=0, name_len=0`

What should I do?

Comment: I ran ```dmesg | grep "EXT4-fs error"``` to see if I have any issues related to the filesystem / journaling system itself.
I returned many time:

```[68241.757233] EXT4-fs error (device vda): htree_dirblock_to_tree:892: inode #533953: block 2108070: comm updatedb.mlocat: bad entry in directory: rec_len is smaller than minimal - offset=0(0), inode=0, rec_len=0, name_len=0```

What does it mean?

Comment: Looks like you have filesystem errors and need to run `fsck` to fix them. What kind of device is a "digital ocean droplet"? Can you boot a Live CD on it, or at least boot it in single-user mode?

Comment: [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) provide servers on which you have what they called "droplets". At first you connect to them with a password they send by email, and then you are (obviously) strongly advised to either change your password or set an ssh key.

Comment: Your filesystem has errors.  Boot into rescue mode and `fsck` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must setup root password:

`sudo passwd`

Then restart the ssh service:

`sudo service ssh reload`

Note: permitting root access especially without password is quite dangerous it makes your system highly vulnerable to external threats.

Comment: I rebooted, it asked me if I want to solve some problems, saying yes solved them. I set a new password as you advised (`sudo passwd` and `sudo service ssh reload`), but I can still log in without any password. I still have `PermitRootLogin without-password`.

Comment: Use this command to re-assign password to root access: `sudo passwd root` set new password to root, if the new password is accepted. try `su root` and see if you are asked for password to root.

Comment: Thanks! I think it did not ask for my password because I only need to enter it once per session. Problem solved!