# cannot remount /dev/sda2 read-write, is write-protected

Tags: boot, mount, filesystem, disk, fsck

I'm using ubuntu 16.04LTS on intel Core i3-6006U, 2.0GHz Asus pc.When I boot the pc I realized that there are some hard drive problems and it's not able to boot on ubuntu.
I tried the answer mentioned in this question: [fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually) and I run this command:

```
fsck -fy /dev/sda2
```

After that I rebooted the pc and it's able to boot on ubuntu successfully.However when I run :

```
apt-get update
```

I got many warnings and errors mentioned that `the file system is read-only`.

I tried different propositions mentioned in this question: [How to fix “sudo: unable to open … Read-only file system”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197459/how-to-fix-sudo-unable-to-open-read-only-file-system) such as:

1. `sudo fsck -Af -M`
2. `mount -o remount /` it returns : `mount: cannot remount /dev/sda2 read-write, is write-protected`

and the other solutions mentioned in the question but no vain.How can I fix this? Should I reinstall ubuntu or does this due to a hardware problem?

Comment: `sudo apt install smartmontools` then a `sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda`  What's the output?  Please [edit] your answer and put the output there.

Comment: @Fabby I'm not able to install smartmontools

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: `E: failed to fetch http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/smartmontools/smartmontools_6.4+svn4214-1_amd64.deb  Could not open file /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/smartmontools_6.4+svn4214-1_amd64.deb - open (30: Read-only file system) [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

Comment: Sorry, I should have said: Boot from a live USB and do that there...

Comment: @Fabby I'm using another pc to ask my question because I'm not able to open neither a browser neither to plug a usb key to copy the error into a file  and paste it in my question.

Comment: @para008 -- he means, boot up to a live USB version of Ubuntu, and run the commands there.  Your disk has the possibility of being damaged, and that is what @Fabby is wanting you to check with `smartmontools`.  This page may also be interesting...  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: You don't need to install `smartmontools` to check SMART status. Just start the `Disks` application, select the disk, select `SMART Data & Tests`.

Comment: @heynnema I selected Smart Data & Tests and I try the tests

Comment: in the Overall Assessment I have Disk is OK, 5776 bad sectors

Comment: With that many bad sectors, it could well be your hard drive which is causing you problems.

Answer (score 3):

**From the comments...**

---

*You don't need to install `smartmontools` to check SMART status. Just start the `Disks` application, select the disk, select `SMART Data & Tests`.*

*@heynnema I selected `Smart Data & Tests` and I try the tests*

*in the Overall Assessment I have Disk is OK, **5776 bad sectors***

---

**Because of the number of bad sectors, your hard disk may be defective.**

**Be prepared to backup your data, if possible.**

However, lets try the following test.

**To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...**

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**If for some reason you can't do the above...**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: I tried this but it does not work and I'm not able to reinstall ubuntu from a bootable usb key.I think that the hard disk was defected.

Comment: I didn't ask you to reinstall Ubuntu. Which of the above methods in my answer did you try, and how far did you get? Did you receive any error messages?

Comment: I tried the second and I didn't get any errors

Comment: It sounds like your hard disk is bad. Connect an external USB hard disk drive or flash key, boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, and backup your important files to the external.