# File system keeps going into read-only

Tags: filesystem, ext4

I keep getting back to this same issue that occurs on a VM.

Proxmox Virtual Environment 5.4-3 
Running a VM of Ubuntu 19.04

Every few days the file system goes read-only with errors like:

```
systemd-journald[400]: Failed to write entry (25 items, 690 bytes), ignoring: Read-only filesystem
```

I end up running this, which fixes the problem.
[How to fix "sudo: unable to open ... Read-only file system"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197459/how-to-fix-sudo-unable-to-open-read-only-file-system)

```
Sudo fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sda1
```

checking dmesg, I see the following errors

```
EXT4-FS (sda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
EXT4-FS (sda2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
```

Any ideas what is causing this or how I can prevent it?

Comment: AFAIK the usual cause of a file system remounted R/O is a hardware error on the device. Of course in a VL it could be a real hardware error, or some error in the virtualization code.

Comment: Classic symptom of a faulty hard drive, not an Ubuntu issue. Test your hardware using the *host* OS. Check your *host* virtualization software's support - look for improper storage settings or matching bug reports..