# i have read-only file system error

Tags: boot, 18.04, read-only, virtual-console

I'm running Ubuntu MATE 18.04 on an Acer Swift 1 laptop, I'm getting this error error screen.

[image: motd]

I tried everything I know. I can't even install Windows. I tried to install Windows 7, Windows 8 and Windows 10 from a USB drive. My laptop doesn't have a CD/DVD drive.

Comment: Unless you mounted your *fs* (file-system) read-only intentionally, the reason will be corruption was detected, and RO was used to prevent further data loss. You should boot a 'live' system (so *fs* is not in-use) and `fsck` (file system check) it.  It's far easier & faster from a 'live' system than trying to do it whilst the system is running (and far safer too!)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "sudo: unable to open ... Read-only file system"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197459/how-to-fix-sudo-unable-to-open-read-only-file-system)

Comment: how can i do that ? i mean, liveusb with ubuntu 18.04.3 ? or ?

Comment: Yep, Ubuntu (or flavor of Ubuntu) install media when used with the "Try Ubuntu" is a perfect 'live' environment, and what I'd use.  *It need not be the same version, though I'd try and use a recent version, and not a version of 15 years ago*

Comment: can u link me ?

Comment: i have to choose from ubuntu flavours but idk which one is good

Comment: Whichever you have around or is easy to get. They will all be the same for what you want to do with them (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours or https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and all be equal to Ubuntu itself.  You only want to boot & use it, not install or keep anything.

Comment: download and tried to boot , i have black screen with "minimal BASH-like editing is supported. for the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions."

Comment: "GNU GRUB version 2.04" idk what it means... now i have to write something "grub>_" idk what commands i need to use here...... do u know that ?

Comment: It sounds like you're in `grub rescue` to me, which i would take as you're attempting to boot your HDD/SSD and not your downloaded & written 'live' media. Many boxes require a fn to be pressed to allow booting thumb-drives so maybe you didn't press it, or hit the wrong key. I'd also 'check disc for detects' to ensure media write & ISO download was perfect before I trusted it with `fsck` job. https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck

Comment: If you need someone to help you walk through this, I'd suggest using a support method that allows for it (not the Q&A format of Ask Ubuntu) such as IRC (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IRC/ChannelList), Support options available can be seen at https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/community-support/709

Comment: i cannot get half of things u are saying mate ((( maybe i need to change bios settings to read usb... i already did that but idk... im dumb af

Comment: @karel fyi: since 18.04 you cannot run fsck from the recovery menu or console terminal, as the system disk is now mounted r/w. You have to boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB to fsck now.

Comment: @nodo313 Please see my answer. Start comments to me with "@heynnema" or I may miss them. If the answer is helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark icon just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB

  - plug in a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
  - power on the computer and wait for the BIOS splash screen
  - most systems can bring up a boot menu from a function key, like F10 or F12
  - select the USB flash key
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`