# Cannot write to storage partition?

Tags: hard-drive

I keep getting this error

```
y9@ubuntu-desktop:~$ sudo mv parallel_studio_xe_2020_cluster_edition.tgz /media/y9/Storage
[sudo] password for y9: 
mv: inter-device move failed: 'parallel_studio_xe_2020_cluster_edition.tgz' to '/media/y9/Storage/parallel_studio_xe_2020_cluster_edition.tgz'; unable to remove target: Read-only file system
```

I don't know how to fix this. Can anyone help? I already tried doing fsck.

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly the same question but you may have an answer in this ticket: [How to fix "sudo: unable to open ... Read-only file system"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197459/how-to-fix-sudo-unable-to-open-read-only-file-system)

A file system can be switched to read only by the system if there is a consistency problem detected. You can switch it back as mentioned in the ticket above.