# Write permission denied for owner even though full permission is listed

Tags: permissions, mount, read-only

**Update:** to anyone having a similar issue read the comments for the solution

I have a dual boot system and a few partitions distributed along 3 HDDs in my case. They all mount automatically on my KDE at startup and I've never had **any** problems with deleting, creating or transferring files between them, but all of a sudden my write permissions have been denied. Which is pretty weird considering that the output for `ls -l` for all of my partitions still gives me this:

```
alex@alex-ubuntu:/media/alex$ ls -l
total 148
drwxrwxrwx 1 alex alex 65536 Oct 12 18:14 Backup
drwxrwxrwx 1 alex alex  4096 Mar 30  2019 DCC68E14C68DEF58
drwxrwxrwx 1 alex alex  4096 Oct 12 18:14 Downloads
drwxrwxrwx 1 alex alex  4096 Oct 12 18:14 Games
drwxrwxrwx 1 alex alex  4096 Oct 12 18:14 Videos
drwxrwxrwx 1 alex alex  8192 Oct 12 19:11 Windows
```

Not even sudo commands for copying or creating files are working anymore:

```
alex@alex-ubuntu:/media/alex/Videos$ sudo touch test.txt
[sudo] password for alex: 
touch: cannot touch 'test.txt': Read-only file system
alex@alex-ubuntu:/media/alex/Videos$
```

I've done some research but all the similar cases I've found were those where the user didn't have full permission or `root` still had the ownership, so it was almost as simple as using `chmod` or `chown` to address the issue. I have absolutely no clue on what could've been causing this, especially given that my external HDD still works flawlessly when connected, for instance.

Here's the `mount` output:

```
alex@alex-ubuntu:~$ mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=2994076k,nr_inodes=748519,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=607456k,mode=755)
/dev/sdc5 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
none on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=28,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=434)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_1885.snap on /snap/core18/1885 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/exercism_5.snap on /snap/exercism/5 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_9993.snap on /snap/core/9993 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1506.snap on /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_145.snap on /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/discord_115.snap on /snap/discord/115 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/heroku_3993.snap on /snap/heroku/3993 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/postman_127.snap on /snap/postman/127 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_9279.snap on /snap/snapd/9279 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/vlc_1700.snap on /snap/vlc/1700 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/dev/sdc7 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_9607.snap on /snap/snapd/9607 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_10126.snap on /snap/core/10126 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=607452k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
/dev/sda1 on /media/alex/Videos type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdb2 on /media/alex/Downloads type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/alex/Backup type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdc2 on /media/alex/DCC68E14C68DEF58 type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdc1 on /media/alex/Windows type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdc3 on /media/alex/Games type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/fuse on /run/user/1000/doc type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

Comment: Read-only is different from permission denied. Can you post the output of `mount` with no arguments? Also, are they Windows drives?

Comment: @PixelatedFish yes, all of them are ntfs/windows drives. I'll edit the original post to include the `mount` output because of its lenght

Comment: The mount output confirms that the drive is mounted read-only, so my answer still stands. If they are actual Windows installs, and not just drives that happen to be NTFS for some other reason, you should disable quick start in Windows, though this may not be the only problem. Think linked questions show how to remount a drive as read-write and check for damage with `fsck` You should not remount as read-write until you have confirmed the drives are not damaged and have disabled quick start, as it can lead to other problems too. (actually, it might be called Windows Fast boot, I don't remember.)

Comment: Well, actually Windows is installed on `/sdc1`. All the others are just NTFS disks indeed. I'll check whether quick start is enabled or not, tho.
Do you have any clue on what could've caused this change? Because at least by the end of September they were still RW disks

Comment: @AlexBraga NTFS partitions are bound to have problems with linux eventually. You can periodically, from windows, run a `chkdsk` on these to avoid problems.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if you don't have to store things on a Windows boot volume, you shouldn't use NTFS, as the Linux driver is purely based on reverse engineering.

Comment: I was only able to run `fsck` after booting to a live disc. I ran `fsck` on my ubuntu disk and `ntfsfix` on my other disk/partitions. It didn't seem to identify any error, but after I reboot to KDE and ran `mount` they were now mounted as `rw`, except for Windows disk, which remained `ro`. It seems that if Windows isn't **completely** shut down it can lead to this kind of issue and, in fact, my last Windows session didn't shut down properly. As soon as I login to Windows again and reboot back to Linux I'll leave my feedback here

Comment: That is correct. Windows will sometimes store data written to a disk in a different place then the file itself, and the writes the data to the files when shut down. When you have bad settings or don't shutdown properly, this often doesn't happen until the next time you use your computer.

Comment: I confirm that the issue was due to an unsuccessful attempt to shut down Windows. Log in back to Windows and restarting to Linux solved the problem and now all my disks/partitions are mounted as rw. Thanks

Comment: @AlexBraga Comments can be deleted without warning. Feel free to post an answer and after a few days you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message shows that `/media/alex/Videos`, whichever drive that is, is mounted as read only see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1283610/write-permission-denied-for-owner-even-though-full-permission-is-listed) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197459/how-to-fix-sudo-unable-to-open-read-only-file-system). This could be due to a system error, or (though more prevalent in external drives) the drive locking itself due to a hardware error. If this is the case, you should back up your data soon, as the hard drives may become corrupted or cease to function. If there is not a problem with the drive, check for bad entries in `/etc/fstab`

### Edit from comments (so it doesn't get deleted)

As it turns out, they were NTFS drives, some with windows installed. The solution stated as working by the OP was to simply log back in to Windows and perform a proper shutdown, then reboot into Linux. For anyone else having this problem, you should make sure to shutdown your computer properly, and disable Windows Fast Boot, as it can prevent you from accessing Linux and cause other problems as well.