# Read-only filesystem with corrupt Windows installation

Tags: read-only

My 1tb hdd is read-only. I followed the steps shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197459/how-to-fix-sudo-unable-to-open-read-only-file-system)

and got this output:

```
WARNING: blksize option is ignored because ntfs-3g must calculate it.
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
Could not mount read-write, trying read-only
```

Tough part is that my Windows installation is corrupted after my system crashed & took my time, gpu, and ssd with it (which is also when I last used Windows). This has happened several times before but the solution was to simply do a clean shutdown on Windows, which I can't even do anymore. Also not sure if re-installing windows (which I might do sometime soon) means I can clear the cache. If anyone can help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Can you backup the files from the read-only drive and format it (and format the Windows drive also)?

Comment: Are Windows and Ubuntu installed on the same disk?  It sounds like the drive is dying.  If I were you, if you don't have good backups, I would run a live session of Ubuntu (Try Ubuntu) and back up the data now to a different disk before this one dies completely

Comment: No way to get the cached data flushed if the Windows install is broken.  After reinstalling Windows, run chkdsk on the file system to get back as much as possible.  The Linux ntfsfix command (sort of fsck  for ntfs) it usually considered less capable than chkdsk, and not recommended.

Comment: `ntfsfix` is not capable at all of correcting NTFS file system errors, it merely marks the partition as needing error correction that must be done with Windows tools.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Windows 10 using the same disk alongside Debian in another partition, and it started to appear this error. My solution was to run as superuser the ***ntfsfix*** command on the partition with the problem.

```
$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdx
```

Comment: I would also check the disk partitioning and output of `dmesg`. Beware of overlapping partitions.